# UWP Custom Map for a Building

Tags: c#, uwp

Is it possible to use the Map API with a custom designed map?  I'd like to build an app using a map of the building I work in, with all the fancy map abilities:  zoom, pan, pushpins, points of interest, etc.

---

Here is the code I'm using to replace the default map:

```
 MapZoomLevelRange range;
        range.Min = 0;
        range.Max = 5;
         
        LocalMapTileDataSource dataSource = new LocalMapTileDataSource("ms-appx:///Assets/Maps/{zoomlevel}/{x}/{y}.png");
        
        MapTileSource tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);
        tileSource.ZoomLevelRange = range;
        tileSource.Layer = MapTileLayer.BackgroundReplacement;
        TestMap1.Style = MapStyle.None;
        tileSource.IsFadingEnabled = false;
        TestMap1.TileSources.Add(tileSource);
```

I am now working on restricting the size of the map to the number of tiles I have.  Horizontally the map repeats over and over.  Vertically, it only shows based on the height of the tiles available.

Comment: Could you please detail "a custom designed map" here?

Comment: By custom, I meant to replace the default map entirely.  I did figure out that part.

I do have an issue with the horizontal panning.  The map just repeats over and over.  Is there a way to limit the map frame to only one set of tiles?